# Issue with new lines in a JTextArea

Tags: java

I am trying to create a chat program. Every time a player presses enter, a message object will be created from the contents of the lower JTextArea and it will be added on the top JTextArea: ([shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNBte.png))

This is how I am setting up my upper JTextArea:

```
private void setUpPanel() {
    Font font = new Font("Monospace", Font.PLAIN, 14);
    textPanel = new JTextArea();
    textPanel.setForeground(Color.green);
    textPanel.setBounds(0, 0, 680, 450);
    textPanel.setFont(font);
    textPanel.setLineWrap(true);
    textPanel.setWrapStyleWord(true);
}
```

And this is the way I am appending text the upper JTextArea (output) from the lower JTextArea (input). This class implements a KeyListener

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if (e.getKeyCode() != 10)
        return;
    // Sends a message if the player presses enter
    sendMessage();
    updatePosition();
}

private void sendMessage() {
    Message message = new Message(input.getText(), "Pablo");
    output.append(message.getMessage());
    input.setText("> ");
    input.setCaretColor(Color.green);
}
```

The problem is the line spacing. I want every line appended to be on a new line. However [this is what happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODT92.png). The second message is never on a new line for some reason. So I tried adding \n to every message, and it was skipping lines randomly sometimes:

```
Pablo: First line
Pablo: Second line

Pablo: Third line

Pablo: Fourth line
```

Does anyone know any approach I can do so lines only take up their corresponding line? Thanks

**EDIT:**

this is the updatePosition() method

```
private void updatePosition() {
    final ScheduledExecutorService exec = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

    exec.schedule(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            input.setCaretPosition(2);
        }
    }, 1, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}
```

I also changed the output (upper box) to a JTextPane and changed the sendMessage() method to this

```
private void sendMessage() {
    Message message = new Message(input.getText(), "Pablo");
    output.setText(output.getText() + message.getMessage() );
    input.setText("> ");
    input.setCaretColor(Color.green);
}
```

I still got the same problem:

```
Pablo: First linePablo: second line
Pablo: third line
Pablo: fourth line
Pablo: fifth line
```

EDIT 2:

I was thinking of checking line by line which line is empty in the JTextPane but getText() returns only a String not an array of Strings?

Comment: can you show updatePosition() ?

Comment: Can you change JTextArea to JTextPane?

Comment: try setting a breakpoint on the output.append line and see the value of each string being appended. it looks like the first message doesnt have a newline on the end of it while the rest do.

Comment: You can get other advantages of using JtextPane in future for your chat application , implementing color changes ,font changes, html support etc. Hence I recommend to use JTextPane over JTextArea

Comment: @Addy how would I append to a JTextPane, output.setText(output.getText + message)? or what do you recommend. I edited my question to show you what happened.

Comment: Does anyone know why? You